# Botframework and Teams SSO

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

When adding an authenticated bot to Teams it seems to me that there is no way to not having the SignIn button appears.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot) the Sequence Diagram shows the "Click on sign in button" from user.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample) the "Test the bot locally" (in the Emulator) and "Test the deployed bot" (in the Web Chat) paragraphs contains the "Select the Sign in box" step.
(Just as a side note, the "Testing the bot locally in Teams", despite the title, explains how to test the bot with Web chat! Adding "Like the Emulator, this test doesn't allow you to access Teams-specific functionality.")

And finally, [here](https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2017/01/07/transparent-bot-authentication-with-microsoft-teams/) there is an hack from 2017 on how to cope with that limitation.

Is the situation still the same of 2017? Is it really not possible to hide the SignIn button at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to authenticate the user without having to click the signin button? If yes, that is not currently possible. User has to click on sign in button and go through the authentication process. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) for Auth in Bot. SSO is currently not supported for Bots. It is something that we are working on but we do not have a firm ETA to share with you.

**Updates: 11/04/2020** -
Single sign-on (SSO) is supported for bots now. Please take a look at [SSO in Bots documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots).

Comment: Thanks @Gousia-MSFT. Is it something missing on the Teams side or on the Bot side?

Comment: SSO is currently not supported for a Bot inside Teams.

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed-MSFT. Have this feature on hold since a long time.

Comment: Posted a feedback on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/2351)